# Devise authenticated route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm using devise for auth and want to have the authenticated user route to locations#show. A user belongs to a location. I've tried a couple things including this in routes

```
authenticated :user do
    match 'locations/:id' => 'locations#show', :as => :root
  end
```

Unfortunately that doesn't change a thing and routes to home#index even when logged in. My full routes file

```
 authenticated :user do
    match 'locations/:id' => 'locations#show', :as => :root
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  resources :locations
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

Any ideas on how to have the root show the location id when a user is logged in?

Comment: Why not map `root` to the required route? If the user is unauthenticated, (and you have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the locations_controller), they will be redirected to the sign_in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up first defining the after sign in path in my applications controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.class == User
      location_path(resource.location) 
    elsif resource.class == Location
      location_path(resource) 
    end
  end
```

Then I setup my route like this

```
 authenticated :user do
    devise_for :users do
      get "/", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    end
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see all available routes related to devise by running following command in your terminal.

```
rake routes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a root with a different name inside the authenticated block like this:

```
authenticated :user do
    root to: 'locations#show', :as => authenticated_root
end
```